# In C++11, can a global object be instantiated by a function call?

Tags: c++11, object, c++17

There are two files ObjectCreator.h and ObjectCreator.cpp that declare and define the following function.

In ObjectCreator.h

```
#include "Object.h"

Object* Create_Object();
```

In ObjectCreator.cpp

```
#include "ObjectCreator.h"

Object* Create_Object()
{
   return new Object();
}
```

The question is, can I create a global instance of Object in the following way in a main.cpp file?

In main.cpp

```
#include "ObjectCreator.h"

static Object* object = Create_Object();

int main()
{
   // Nothing here
}
```

The best way I could ask this question was an example and I have verified this is possible. I am just not sure if it is possible in C++11 or what the technical term for this is. I am aware objects can be instantiated globally, I am just not sure if they can be done in this specific way in C++11.

Comment: A little impolite to force your OS to clean up after you :-)

Comment: I know it's weird, but there is a reason I am doing this. Is there a name for this? I want to confirm I can do this in C++11 documentation, but I don't know what to look up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that and it is legal C++.

There are three three steps for initialization of non-local variables, such as the one you have.

1. Zero initialization
2. Constant initialization
3. Dynamic initialization

In your case, `object` will be initialized in the last step.

You can read more on the three types of initialization [from the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init).